# Fundamental confusion on set theory and permutations

Tags: terminology, permutations

I am confused on the following: A set does not have any order. Now I read that a permutation is a bijection of a set. But doesn't this imply an order?
I mean a bijection is a one-to-one function from a set A to a set B. So if a permutation is a essentially a shuffling of a set and it is equivalent to a bijection doesn't that mean that this shuffling "explicitely" assumes an ordering in the first place? Otherwise there is no permutation of a set as a set has no order.
Can someone help me clear this out?

Comment: No problem with that. A permutation is really a bijection $\pi: A\to A$. In symbols the permutation $(X\mapsto Y, Y\mapsto Z, Z\mapsto X)$ is the same as $(Y\mapsto Z, Z\mapsto X, X\mapsto Y)$ etc.

Comment: No order is assumed. Draw a circle with a few dots in it, say 5. Now draw arrows between the dots such that every dot is the tail of precisely one arrow and every dot is the head of precisely one arrow. That is a bijection; and, there is no particular order on the dots.

Comment: @user18921: What does the arrow represent if not the order?

Comment: @Jim, there is a difference between (I) saying that the set already *had* an ordering on its elements, and (II) saying that the bijection *induces* an ordering.

Comment: @user18921: So bijection creates an ordering?So a bijection is a "random" ordering of a set?

Answer (score 1):

No, the term "permutation", in the lack of further context, means just a bijection. Sometimes when a set is presupposed to have a particular structure a permutation might mean a structure-preserving bijection, or the proper term an *automorphism*.

If you really want to think about permutation only in context of partial orders, then you can always consider the partial order $\{(x,x)\mid x\in X\}$, where no two distinct elements are comparable.

Comment: I am sorry for the question but I am not sure what you mean by a set having a particular structure.I am thinking of a set in the terms of just being a container where an element either is or is not part of the set and order is irrelevant.Can you please explain this one?

Comment: Structure is an additional information. For example, an order, or a binary operation like $+$. $\Bbb Q$ is a set, but we often think about it as a structured set. What structure? It depends on the context, it can be a group with $+$, or an ordered set with $\leq$, or an ordered field with $+,\cdot$ and $\leq$. Or we can endow it with completely different structure altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If the set is finite with $n$ elements, then a order is a bijection between $n$ and the set, this order is defined by $f(1)$ is the first element, $f(2)$ second element... etc. This is sense of a permutation.

Comment: This is confusing. If $f$ is the order, where is the connection to permutations?